# Is it possible to speed up scanning a list of computers for specific service names?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm kind of a newbie to PowerShell and I am currently making a simple service monitoring script.  Right now I have a list of computer names and a list of service names that I scan for.

I save the scan to a log.  I am wondering if there is any way I can speed up my PowerShell code?  I'm not sure if I am using the quickest methods for the job.

Are there any known alternatives to this code that would scan services quicker?

```
$myServices = $PSScriptRoot + "\services.txt" # $PSScriptRoot references current directory
$myServers = $PSScriptRoot + "\servers.txt"
$Log = $PSScriptRoot + "\svclog.csv"
$LogLive = $PSScriptRoot + "\svclogLive.csv"


$serviceList = Get-Content $myServices

Remove-Item -Path $Log


$results = Get-Content $myServers | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
        if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType
        } else {
            # "$_ - Service '$service' does not exist."
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-CSV $Log -notypeinformation

# Create a second current log that Python can read while this script runs
Copy-Item -Path $Log -Destination $LogLive
```

Comment: I would take a look at the PoshRSJob module.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Invoke-command`

```
$serviceList = Get-Content $myServices

#some code

$results = Get-Content $myServers
Invoke-command -ComputerName $results -ScriptBlock {
Param($MyServices)
    Get-Service -Name $MyServices | Select-Object -Property ServiceName, Status, StartType
} -ArgumentList $MyServices,$Null | Select-Object -Property ServiceName, Status, StartType,PSComputerName |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $Log

#For getting starttype in Version 2.0
Get-wmiObject -class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='BITS'" | Select-Object -Property Name, State, startMode
```

Comment: This works quickly.  I had to change the Param to Param($serviceList) to get it working.  I dumps all services for computers on the list.  One thing, it's not giving me the StartType.  That column remains blank.  Do you happen to know why?

Comment: what is the version of PowerShell you are using. the StartType will be available from version 3.0 onwards. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try capturing all of the target server's services in an array and looking through it rather than calling `get-service` on every service you are searching for:

```
$myServices = $PSScriptRoot + "\services.txt" # $PSScriptRoot references current directory
$myServers = $PSScriptRoot + "\servers.txt"
$Log = $PSScriptRoot + "\svclog.csv"
$LogLive = $PSScriptRoot + "\svclogLive.csv"


$serviceList = Get-Content $myServices

Remove-Item -Path $Log


$results = Get-Content $myServers | ForEach-Object {

    # All of the services in one grab
    $serverServices = @(Get-Service -computer $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if ($serverServices) {
        foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
            #Note: this inner use of another $_ may confuse PowerShell... 
            if ($s = ($serverServices | Where {$_.Name -eq $service}))
            {
                $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType
            } else {
                # "$_ - Service '$service' does not exist."
            }
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-CSV $Log -notypeinformation

# Create a second current log that Python can read while this script runs
Copy-Item -Path $Log -Destination $LogLive
```